# What is the replacement of __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ in Swift?

Tags: swift, xctestcase

In objective C, we are using like:

```
XCTFail("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

what is the replacement of this when writing test cases in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, use `"\(#function)"` to replace `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`